# Gtk+ window_state_event

Tags: c++, gtk

I'm not sure about change_mask in window_state_event (GdkWindowState enum) how to correctly handle it.

I tried `if(changed_mask & GDK_WINDOW_STATE_ICONIFIED)...` but it's not working.

**How can i handle window state change?**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to catch the mask, just do:

```
# python
def window_signal (self, widget, event):
    if event.changed_mask == 1 :
        #do your thing

    return True
```

if that's what yo u want. or do you want to set new event?